# Layout of unordered list

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to change the layout items in a list?
I have 6 options (languages) and I'd like to make the layout so that there are only three items in row:

[image]

If I put options to `display:inline;` then all the options are in one line.

Do I need to use JavaScript to change this? I'm not very experienced in JavaScript.

I'm using Joomla 2.5 and the language selector module.

```
<ul class="lang-inline">
<li class="" dir="ltr">
<a href="#"> ENG </a>
</li>
<li class="" dir="ltr">
<a href="#"> FIN </a>
</li>
<li class="" dir="ltr">
<a href="#"> RUS </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

This is the view of "default" on picture. There are options to make it a dropdown, but then there is only one language in a row or all languages in row.

So maybe I need to add custom links and not to use this module? Maybe then I can't layout these links like I want and use JavaScript?

Comment: Showing your code would be helpful.

Comment: Short answer - yes, it is possble. But! How your HTML looks like? What is your CSS?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is something like what you want:

Here is the HTML I used to simulate something like your picture.  I used a "V" in the button to avoid loading a graphic from somewhere, but you get the idea.

```
<div>
    <div class="langs"><span>ENG</span><span>FIN</span><span>RUS</span></div><div class="sbtn">V</div>
</div>
<div id="morelangs" class="hidelangs">
    <div class="langs">
        <div><span>ENG</span><span>FIN</span><span>RUS</span></div>
        <div><span>ENG</span><span>FIN</span><span>RUS</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note the extra two lines of languages under "morelangs".

Here is the CSS I used.  The main trick is the hidelangs class, which uses "display: none;" to hide the other 2 lines of languages.  Also, I use "display: inline-block;" to allow horizontal stacking of some div elements.

```
.hidelangs {
    display: none;
}
.langs {
    display: inline-block;
}
.langs span {
    background-color: #555555;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 80%;
    margin: 0;
}
.sbtn {
    background-color: #999999;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 80%;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JavaScript/jQuery is only used to process click on button-like div, and all it does on click, is either remove the CSS class hidelangs if it is there, or add it if it isn't (toggleClass in jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".sbtn").on("click", function(e) {
        $("#morelangs").toggleClass("hidelangs");
    });
});
```

Working jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5MAwS/) so you can see how it works.  Click the "V" lighter colored button-like div to toggle the extra lines on and off.

You could also switch the button contents to a different image in the click handler as in your picture the arrow is upside-down after click.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it is not possible to do that using the options element with css alone. I recommend using html, css, and javascript. Use UL elements in your html, style it with some css, and use javascript to handle the click events and visibilities.